# How to start two springboot projects at the same time

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My project includes a view service and an interface service. The project directory looks like this:

```
Myproject/
    springboot1/
    springboot2/
```

Both springboot1 and springboot2 can be run separately.The way I start them now is to open both terminals and execute the following commands:

**springboot1**

```
cd Myproject/springboot1/
mvn spring-boot:run
```

**springboot2**

```
cd Myproject/springboot2/
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Is there any way to start two projects at the same time? 
**For example, add a global pom.xml file to the Myproject directory and execute mvn spring-boot:run directly in the Myproject directory.**

Comment: if you use IntelliJ, you can run all of them at once using the Run Dashboard

Comment: @Kartik Thank you for your answer, but I want to get rid of the IDE. The scenario is like this. The two projects are developed by two groups of people. I hope that after a version is developed, it will be automatically built after submitting to our git-server. 
And deploy these two projects. 
I can use the shell to implement it, but I want to know if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, as you mentioned need something like global pom xml way, than that you can be achieved by combing two projects as modules to your packing app(Myproject). Let me give you some idea :

- Create a new springBoot application with global pom file and move all common (1 & 2 project) jar or dependencies to this global pom file. Also, as each application as main application remove that as its no longer required as separate entity but also ensure if you have any custom code in their respective main file than move that code to main file of packaging project.
- Build project 1 and 2 as jar packages and add them into packaging project as dependencies.
- Project springboot1 internal pom will look like :

  ```
  ...
  <groupId>org.springboot1.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>springboot1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  ...
  ```
- Project springboot2 internal pom will look like :

  ```
  ...
  <groupId>org.springboot2.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>springboot2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  ...
  ```
- Packaging project pom will look like :

  ```
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springboot1.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>springboot1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springboot2.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>springboot2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
  ```
- In your packing main file add new locations of the @Components, that are coming from the dependencies

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = 
     {"org.springboot1.module.one.*","org.springboot2.module.two.*"})
  public class Myproject {
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
        SpringApplication.run(Myproject.class, args);
     }
  ```

  }
- Run the main class of the packaging application and it will start with the two dependent projects.

Hope above steps will work with some more changes depending your project structure. Also, for some more clarity you can also refer [Maven Project_Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation)

Comment: In doing so, do I have to package springboot1 and springboot2 into jars first? 
Running mvn spring-boot:run directly in the project directory doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As I mentioned above in respective internal pom `packing type is jar`, so you don't need to build them jar separately rather directly run `mvn clean install` on Main project that will package them into jar in Main project classpath as you have already declared them as dependencies in global pom file (check in my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I still have some problems. Maven reminds me that it can't find org.springboot1.module, org.springboot2.module. 
I don't know what caused the problem. I uploaded my code to github. Can you help me with debugging?https://github.com/jiangbai333/springboot-module-test

Comment: Here is my suggestion before even you start debugging. Look the name `org.springboot1.module` was just an example for your reference in my answer. So pick some spring-boot two simple application and now try to couple them and then see where its getting stuck and fix one by one. As I already mentioned its not going to be straight forward you have to hustle around to make it working. All the Best!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

mvn springboot1/spring-boot:run | mvn springboot2/spring-boot:run

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper Spring Boot application that launches them as separate servlets. They should be in sibling application contexts and share the wrapper application as a parent context. It would look roughly like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder().parent(WrapperApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
        .child(Application1.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
        .sibling(Application2.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
        .run(args);
}
```